# Schedule a BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to schedule my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
// Get the current application descriptor.
ApplicationDescriptor current = ApplicationDescriptor
                        .currentApplicationDescriptor();

// Schedules are rounded to the nearest minute so ensure the
// application is scheduled for at least 1 minute in the future.
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().scheduleApplication(
                        current, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60001, true);
```

For more details you can read this article also.
[Schedule an application to run at a specific time](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/schedule-application-run-specific-time/)

Comment: I have a question about this. What happens if the device is rebooted? The scheduled application will be launched or is necesary to schedule it again?

Comment: it is necesary to schedule it again