# Invoke an application at a particular date

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to schedule application in blackberry.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236108/how-to-schedule-application-in-blackberry)

I just want to know how could I schedule a application by which it starts executing at 
particular date.
Please send me the code as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in the answer to this question: [Schedule a BlackBerry application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236108/how-to-schedule-application-in-blackberry)