# Check if BlackBerry application is already scheduled

Tags: java, blackberry

I have configured my application to run using what is described on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236108/how-to-schedule-application-in-blackberry)

Is there any way to check if my application (a given ApplicationDescriptor) is currently scheduled?

Also what happens if the device is rebooted? Does the application remain scheduled or does it need to be scheduled again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out is to just try restarting your device.    If the schedule isn't preserved, the [docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html) point to a solution for app upgrades by scheduling your app on device restart:

> As a workaround, if an application
>   needs to maintain its scheduled launch
>   after an upgrade it should run on
>   startup and invoke this method to
>   register a scheduled launch of the
>   upgraded version.